# how to extract a subsite files From a WordPress Multisite localhost into a standalone WordPress website (hosting server)

Tags: wordpress, localhost, hosting, data-migration, multisite

I'm working in localhost and I want to know how to find and migrate a specific subsite files from a WordPress Multisite into a standalone WordPress website (hosting server) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not as easy as you may think as you have to extract the correct part of the database as well as all required files from the main installation as well as the media folder for your specific subsite.

A detailed migration procedure is described here: https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/doc/extracting-subsite-multisite-create-new-single-site-install/